# How to install WIFI-adapter TP-Link AC1300 archer T3U in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, tp-link

I'm really new to Ubuntu.
My laptop WIFI is stuck on "airplane mode on" and I'm not able to turn it off.
I thought the HW is damaged and therefore I bought a new WIFI adapter HW.
The adapter installation disk only run on windows and mac.Not in Linux
I have tried some Linux commands I found on the internet to the install drives but without success.
Can someone help if he thinks that the new adapter is the solution?

Thanks
Skeyes

Comment: To reset "Airplane mode", Find the hardware switch, or a `Fn` key combination. Carefully read the keycaps, and the symbols along the keyboard frame just above the keys. [Edit] your question to add laptop manufacturer  and model.

Comment: Thank you waltinator! FN+ F12 did the trick! And intern WIFI module is working.

Comment: Please click the checkmark to "accept" my answer, if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

To reset "Airplane mode", Find the hardware switch, or a `Fn` key combination. Carefully read the keycaps, and the symbols along the keyboard frame just above the keys.